# MySQL query Cross referencing values in columns

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of an issue trying to cross reference some data in the following table. The data in question are lottery results

This is the query i am trying to use to get me started. This will retrieve all tickets that were generated by a specific user for a specific lottery drawing.

```
(SELECT * FROM ticket_results INNER JOIN tickets ON ticket_results.ticket_id=tickets.ticket_id WHERE game_id = 7 and drawing_id = 64 and user_id = 10)
```

Which yields the following results in the sql
[image: Query Results]

Now for each ticket that a user has generated gets split up into this table.  So for example if the game is Mega Millions. We have 5 numbers with 1 Mega ball.  So each of the 5 numbers will get it's own row in this table.

For example - 20, 22, 19, 6, 15 (Megaball = 24)
each number is stored in the `ticket_number` column, the position relative to how it came out is in the `ticket_position` column. So depending on how many numbers are in the game will have an equal amount of rows listed here.

The winning drawing results are stored like this in a table called game_results.
[image: Winning Results]

**The Question**

How can I do a search against this result set to find out which tickets are winners?

So for example, In the game Mega Millions there are multiple ways to win. So lets take the easiest one.  If I match 1 white colored ball in the `ticket_id` I would be a winner.  How do I perform this search? Because it could be any row.

Comment: Where are the winning numbers stored? Can you give an example of the Mega Millions result for that day?

Comment: Yes that would help wouldn't it.  Editing the original post now.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Does ticket_position / result_position matter in determining the winners, or is it enough if ticket_number=result_number and game_id=game_id and result_id=result_id? In plain English: you need to describe how to join the ticket_result on game_results.

Comment: you can join them on game_results.drawing_id